# RobotDyn Uno wifi not working

Tags: arduino

I am using a Uno+WiFi R3 ATmega328P+ESP8266 board, 32Mb flash, USB-TTL CH340G, Micro-USB.

I am able to see the network SSID on my PC and to connect to it, but when I tried to upload a sketch using the Arduino IDE I am getting espcomm_upload_mem failed.

I used the sketch from https://robotdyn.com/uno-wifi-r3-atmega328p-esp8266-32mb-flash-usb-ttl-ch340g-micro-usb.html

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  delay(500);
  Serial.println("AT+CIPMUX=1");
  delay(2000);
  Serial.println("AT+CIPSERVER=1,5000");
  delay(2000);
  Serial.println("AT+CIPSTO=3600");
  delay(2000);
}

void loop() {
  while(Serial.available()) {
    char Rdata;
    Rdata=Serial.read();
    if(Rdata=='A'|Rdata=='a') {
      digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
      delay(50);
    } else if(Rdata=='B'|Rdata=='b') {
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(10);
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(10);
      digitalWrite(13,LOW);
    } else {
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: duplicate of https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=526124.0

Comment: i am trying what u suggested.

Comment: lets try this URL https://medium.com/@oviraj71/uno-wifi-r3-atmega328p-esp8266-8mb-flash-usb-ttl-ch340g-micro-usb-d029614e803f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robotdyn Uno/Mega + WiFi boards have switches to make serial connections of Atmega to Usb, esp8266 to USB and Atmega to esp8266. To flash the esp8266 the switches 5, 6, 7 must be ON. switch 7 is flashing mode. to communicate with esp8266 from Serial Monitor, switches 5 and 6 must be ON.

[image: swithes]

For communication of Atmega with the esp8266 switches 1 and 2 must be ON. In tis settings none of the MCUs is connected to USB. Therefore it is better to use SoftwareSerial on some Atmega pins and connect them with jumpers to the esp8266 header. The header is documented in the [schematic](https://robotdyn.com/pub/media/0G-00005215==UNO+WiFi-R3-AT328-ESP8266-CH340G/DOCS/Schematic==0G-00005215==UNO+WiFi-R3-AT328-ESP8266-CH340G.pdf).

The code in post is for the Atmega directly connected to esp8266 (switches 1,2)

Comment: For communication of Atmega with the esp8266 switches 1 , 2, 3 and 4 must be ON. So you can use USB and without using jumpers

Comment: Or switches 1 , 2, 5 and 6

Comment: Don't use 1+2 at the same time as 3+4 or 5+6, you will have multiple pins driving these lines and may damage the board.